# Using `synchronize` in Ansible provisioner (Vagrant): "ssh: Could not resolve hostname default: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I'd like to perform a very basic task with Ansible: `rsync`ing a local file to a server (here: local vm).

For this, I've installed `ansible` / `vagrant` / `virtualbox`, and created the following minimal `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
end
```

and the following minimal `playbook.yml`, which simply attempts to `synchronize` a local file `f.txt`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Ensure rsync is installed
    apt:
      name: rsync
      state: present
  - name: Ensure rsync is running
    service:
      name: rsync
      state: started
      enabled: true
  - name: Copy a random file
    synchronize:
      src: f.txt
      dest: /home/vagrant/f.txt
```

and attempted running `vagrant up`.

The last task (copying the file) fails with a relatively cryptic error message:

> [...] vagrant@default:/home/vagrant/f.txt", "msg": "ssh: Could not resolve hostname default: Temporary failure in name resolution\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]\n", "rc": 255}

This just looks broken: how is `rsync` supposed to know what `default` means in `vagrant@default:/home/vagrant/f.txt`? It should be Ansible that looks up the IP in its inventory files.

**Full self-contained script that reproduces the error:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eou pipefail

# Delete the `repro`-directory if it already exists
if [ -d './repro' ]
then
  rm -r './repro'
fi

# Create a `repro` directory with bug-reproducer
mkdir repro
cd repro

# Create a `Vagrantfile`, set `ansible` as provisioner
cat <<HEREVAGRANTFILE > Vagrantfile

# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
end
HEREVAGRANTFILE

# Create a file that I'd like to copy
echo "random stuff" > f.txt

# Create an ansible playbook
cat <<ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOK > playbook.yml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Ensure rsync is installed
    apt:
      name: rsync
      state: present
  - name: Ensure rsync is running
    service:
      name: rsync
      state: started
      enabled: true
  - name: Copy a random file
    synchronize:
      src: f.txt
      dest: /home/vagrant/f.txt
ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOK

# If `yamllint` available, run it on the ansible playbook, just in case
if command -v yamllint
then
  yamllint playbook.yml
fi

# Start the vm
vagrant up || true

# Cleanup
vagrant halt
vagrant destroy --force
```

I must be missing something extremely basic. What's going wrong here, how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

---

**What else I've tried:**

- I've tried to run `rsync` manually, this works just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "rsync this, omg" > foo.txt

KEY="$(vagrant ssh-config | grep IdentityFile | sed 's/^  IdentityFile //g')"
rsync \
  --archive \
  --verbose \
  --compress \
  --rsh="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2200 -i $KEY" \
  foo.txt \
  vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/foo.txt
```

- I've tried looking at the synthetic `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory` file, it defines the IP for `default` and generally looks just fine. Why is the `synchronize` task incapable of extracting the correct IP for the `default` vm?
- I tried cloning the repo with examples for Geerling's "Ansible for Devops", and `grep -rHn synchronize`. There is simply nothing there. Am I somehow the first person on the planet trying to move a local file to a server?